# OpenCV - C++ - Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, opencv, processamento-de-imagens, raspberry-pi

Quero que a função fique verificando o tempo todo se há uma impressão digital. Caso haja, quero que inicie o esquema de captura em sequência(os `for` aninhados), porém a função que eu criei não está funcionando dessa forma...

```
void Leitor::iniciarLeitura()
{
    Mat frame;
    string cmd = "raspistill -n -q 100 -o verifica.jpeg";
    system(cmd.c_str());
    delay(1000);
    frame = imread("verifica.jpeg");
    if (haDigital(frame)) {
        string lado = "D";
        string caminhoImagem = "/home/pi/digitais/";
        stringstream ss;

       ss << (buscaNumeroVoluntario() + 1);
       const char* numero = ss.str().c_str();
       string cmd = "mkdir " + caminhoImagem + numero;

       for (int mao = 0; mao < 2; mao++) {
           system(cmd.c_str());
           for (int dedo = 1; dedo < 6; dedo++) {
               for (int rep = 0; rep < 5; rep++) {
                    string caminho = caminhoImagem + numero + "/" + lado + "/" + to_string(mao) + "_" + to_string(dedo) + "_" + to_string(rep) + ".jpeg";
                    try
                    {

                        capturaDigitais(caminho);
                        delay(1000);
                    }

                    catch (...)
                    {
                        cout << "erro";
                    }
                }
            }
            lado = "E";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        sched_yield();
    }
}
```

Estou usando: Raspberry Pi 2; Visual Studio 2017; C++; OpenCV.

Comment: E como você chama esta função?

Comment: `pthread_create(&t_leitor, NULL, Leitor::iniciarLeitura_wrapper, &leitor);`

Comment: [Link para o projeto](https://github.com/levezf/SEAID), caso ajude.